# Jitsi meet plus in flutter is not working on android 12

Tags: android, flutter, android-12, jitsi-meet

When run on android 12 it's show me an error like this

```
[INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI:
/data/app/vmdl752003294.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #235):
org.jitsi.meet.sdk.ConnectionService: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires
that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are
present]
```

Here is my androidManifest.xml file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="eu.buddybee.consultancy"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GALLERY"/>
    <!-- Provide required visibility configuration for API level 30 and above -->
    <queries>
        <!-- If  app checks for Web support -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>
        <!-- If  app checks for mail support -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="mailto" />
        </intent>
        <!-- If  app checks for SMS support -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
        </intent>
        <!-- If  app checks for call support -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

    <application tools:replace="android:label" android:label="BuddyBee" android:name="${applicationName}" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:exported="true" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme" android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- Deep linking -->
            <meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="buddybee.eu" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="buddybee.eu" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.buddybee.eu" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.buddybee.eu" />
                <data android:scheme="www"/>
            </intent-filter>



        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data android:name="flutterEmbedding" android:value="2" />
    </application>
    <!-- <service android:name="org.jitsi.meet.sdk.ConnectionService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_TELECOM_CONNECTION_SERVICE" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.telecom.ConnectionService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service> -->
</manifest>
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Take a look at the issue: https://github.com/gunschu/jitsi_meet/issues/356.

Comment: I tried but not woking

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I use jitsi_meet_wrapper, works fine.